# How to show friendly url when using Facets search?

Tags: commerce, search

I installed the commerce_kickstart distribution. Its products pages shows facets search blocks to filter the products.

When using these filters the url change to a not friendly url. How can change this? How to show the taxonomies terms names instead.

Look my capture below:

I mean to change this:

```
http://localhost/commerce_kickstart/es/products?f[0]=field_collection%3A81
```

to something like

```
http://localhost/commerce_kickstart/es/products/field_collection/cds
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing yesterday and came across [Facet API Pretty Paths](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi_pretty_paths)

> Enables pretty paths for searches with Facet API. You will likely use this module in combination with either Search API or Apache Solr Search Integration.

I haven't had a chance to try it yet but looks promising...

Comment: I just enabled the module. I works fine since you get clean urls, but when applying a filter in a facet block all the other facet blocks disappear.  Even when the situation is that they should be there. This behavior is wrong in my case. If I disable the module the behavior is right again.

Comment: That's a shame I was hoping that module would solve the same problem for me in a few weeks. Back to the drawing board I guess...

Comment: my mistake, it works fine. I just forget to allow the block to be shown in the new ulr (the url generated by this module)

Comment: @chefnelone Can you give more detail about the configuration settings for Facet API Pretty Paths. I have also installed this module and enabled it. For me, it does not appear to turn on pretty URLs out-of-the-box - I still get what you were getting - something like: products?f[0]=field_collection%3A81

Comment: The drupal recruiter distribution is an example of using facetapi_pretty_paths with faceted / searching / navigation filter / "drill-down": https://drupal.org/project/recruiter - on this page you'll find more information including how to run a demo via simplytest.me with just a few clicks! My approach (for myself too) would be to study how this works and "cherry-pick" what you need for your work.